# DisMan Monitoring - traps not being generated

Tags: snmp

In order to set up a self-monitoring of a linux OS (CentOS) in order to send traps if a condition occurs i have configured the lines

com2sec notConfigUser  default     Public0
group   notConfigGroup v1          notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup v2c         notConfigUser
view    systemview                 included      .1
access  notConfigGroup ""          any         noauth    exact  systemview systemview none

### for disk query

disk / 100000000

trap2sink 10.10.64.132

## authorization for self monitoring

rouser        admin
iquerySecName admin

## define message to send OID to monitor threshold values

monitor -r 10 DiskAlmostFull dskPercent < 90
monitor -r 10 machineTooBusy hrProcessorLoad < 90

But the traps are generated only when i restart the snmpd deamon.

I have tried to troubleshoot this issue without success.

Any held will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem, I discovered the following explanation in "man snmpd.conf".
Section "monitor [OPTIONS] NAME EXPRESSION" states:
"Note that the event will only be triggered once, when the expression first  matches. This monitor entry will not fire again  until the monitored condition first becomes false, and then matches again."
You may not like the answer, but the monitor command behaves as advertised.